# How can I get the wacom settings panel (from regular Ubuntu) in XUbuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, system-settings, wacom

I liked being able to change tablet settings, especially button mapping and all that, from the settings tool in Unity and GNOME. Is there some way to get this or an equivalent GUI-based wacom manager on XUbuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any official support for an xfce wacom applet, but [this project](https://github.com/Zeioth/XFCE-Wacom-Settings) might interest you.

Comment: Outdated solution, it no longer works.